# All declarations of 'WeakMap' must have identical type parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm building Ionic App and everything is going fine, but when I cloned my source code to another machine, I get an error as shown in the image.

although the app is compiling without errors at the first machine I checked Ionic, npm, typescript and node versions and they are identical for the two machines.

what I'm missing here!?

[image]

Comment: It's like you are using two different type for T i.e boolean and number both .The type should be same

Comment: what happens if you add this to the `compilerOptions` array of the `tsconfig.json` file?: `"types": ["lodash"],`

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14324) where the users recommend to add `"skipLibCheck": true` in the `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: @sebaferreras your suggested solutions didn't fix this issue, I tried to create a new project to compare the configurations but I got the same error for the new project too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to document this in case anyone has the same issue I was able to fix this by deleting global `node_module` folder in path

`C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

and in my case, there was another folder at `C:\node_modules` as indicated at the very end of the error message

Comment: Deleting the globals  screws up your machine. You will have to download all those again

Comment: Yes, this what I intended to do re-download everything to fix any broken references or corrupted files